# MFMailComposeViewController crushed when i'm trying to send mail. I'm working with both UINavigationController and UITabBarController

Tags: xcode, ios7, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I created an application using both UINavigationController and UITabBarController. I'm trying to send mail using "MFMailComposeViewController" but get ab error and the application is crushed. 
My code:

- (IBAction)SendMail:(UIButton *)sender {
  if([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail]) {
      MFMailComposeViewController *mailCont = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
      mailCont.mailComposeDelegate = self;

  ```
  [mailCont setSubject:@"yo!"];
  [mailCont setToRecipients:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"joel@stackoverflow.com"]];
  [mailCont setMessageBody:@"Don't ever want to give you up" isHTML:NO];

  [self presentModalViewController:mailCont animated:YES];
  ```

  }

  (void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController*)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError*)error {
  [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

and i did import: #import

## import  and use the MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
mailComposer.mailComposeDelegate = self;
```

instead of

```
mailComposer.delegate = self;
```